# Morph a shape in WPF

Tags: wpf, animation

I want to animate the form o a circle into a square. The same way we did it in the flash animations time, but in WPF.
I'm open to any suggestion on how to approach it. I do have my path data for the final and initial shapes but I cannot find anything relevant.

My google search only go into the directions of animating a form along a path. This is not what I want, I want my object to stay stationary but change it outline from a circle to a square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could animate the `RadiusX` and `RadiusY` properties of a Rectangle like this:

```
<Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50"
           Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="3">
    <Rectangle.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard BeginTime="0:0:2">
                    <DoubleAnimation 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RadiusX"
                        To="0" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RadiusY"
                        To="0" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Rectangle.Triggers>
</Rectangle>
```

---

Alternatively, animate the `CornerRadius` of a Border with a custom animation:

```
<Border Width="100" Height="100" CornerRadius="50"
        BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3">
    <Border.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard BeginTime="0:0:2">
                    <local:CornerRadiusAnimation 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="CornerRadius"
                        To="0" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Border.Triggers>
</Border>
```

The CornerRadiusAnimation:

```
public class CornerRadiusAnimation : AnimationTimeline
{
    public CornerRadius To { get; set; }

    public override Type TargetPropertyType
    {
        get { return typeof(CornerRadius); }
    }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new CornerRadiusAnimation { To = To };
    }

    public override object GetCurrentValue(object defaultOriginValue, object defaultDestinationValue, AnimationClock animationClock)
    {
        if (!animationClock.CurrentProgress.HasValue)
        {
            return defaultOriginValue;
        }

        var p = animationClock.CurrentProgress.Value;
        var from = (CornerRadius)defaultOriginValue;

        return new CornerRadius(
            (1 - p) * from.TopLeft + p * To.TopLeft,
            (1 - p) * from.TopRight + p * To.TopRight,
            (1 - p) * from.BottomRight + p * To.BottomRight,
            (1 - p) * from.BottomLeft + p * To.BottomLeft);
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, did not think about the particular solution for square-circles using radius but .. you are totally right, that will be goo enough. Can you please elaborate on the custom animation thing ?  My circle-square will contain buttons and stuff so border would be perfect for the job

Comment: [Custom Animations Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/custom-animations-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: the link was actually not useful at all, but still I use the radius solution and it kind of worked for me :)

Comment: Why not? The section [Create a Custom Animation Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/custom-animations-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#create-a-custom-animation-class) explains what to do. Derive from AnimationTimeline and override two methods and two properties.

Comment: I've been there but Im sorry, I'm lost there, I would need an example

Comment: Please see the edited answer for a simple example.

Comment: Wow, I'm away from the computer for the weekend, but this is an awesome response !

Comment: I created a border like `<Border x:Name="test" Width="300" Height="300" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Red"/>` then called the anim like: `var anim = new CornerRadiusAnimation { To = new CornerRadius(150,150,150,150), Duration = AnimTime};
            test.BeginAnimation(Border.CornerRadiusProperty, anim);` But nothing happens :(

Comment: See the edit. CreateInstanceCore needs to copy the To property.

Comment: Wow, that wasn't a short ride. I do see the thing get rounded now but .. it does not hides the parts outside the circle. I added a borderthickness to the border being animated to be able to see it. Inside it I have my stackpanel with the 3 buttons.  When animating I do see the border getting round but the content is fully visible. Tried with cliptobounds = true. Same effect. Do you follow what I mean or would you rather see a picture and the actual code ?

Comment: I think this question has been answered. I saw your other question, but that's a different story than "morphing a shape".

Comment: you are totally right. The form has been morphed. I assumed that by morphing it it will obscure its content. My fault. Wil mark your answer as valid. Thanks a tone for your time.

Comment: The problem is that Border does not clip its child element at its rounded corners. You are however not the first one who encounters this issue. Search StackOverflow.